# Flask send JSON to the front end within a python function from the backend that also needs to return a `send_file()`?

Tags: python, flask, frontend

I'm trying to see if there is a simple way to send information to the front end of my website within a function from the backend in my python code that needs to return a `send_file()` call at the end. I'm trying to download files from YouTube using pytube and then send those videos to the end user. However, during the process of downloading said videos, I want to show the progress of the function that's running by passing a percent of completion number to the front end.

This is basically what I have.

```
@app.route('/main', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def main(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        files = get_files(current_user) 
        return files or redirect(url_for('home')) 
return render_template('main.html', user = current_user)

def get_files(user):
    if not user:
        return None:
    zip_bytes = BytesIO()
    counter = 0 
    with ZipFile(zip_bytes, "w") as zip:
        while True:
            counter++

            #send counter value to front-end to update progress bar

            #code for generating files and adding them into the zip file

    return send_file(zip_bytes, download_name=f"something.zip", as_attachment=True)
```

So what I want to do, is to send the counter over to my front-end, to change some HTML on my page to say something like "3/10 files completed", "4/10 files completed", etc.

If possible, please explain it in simple terms because I don't know much terminology in the world of web development.

Comment: you are probably too far from a working solution, so this might get closed ... but general strategy is create 1 endpoint that will `/start_download` a download and update some database with progress and return a unique id, then create one endpoint for `/progress/<unique_id>` that will return the "progress" from the database the first endpoints job is filling, and lastly create one endpoint for `/download/<unique_id>` that downloads a finished file

Answer (score 0):

You need a table to keep track of tasks with the following rough attributes

- id
- uuid
- percentage_completed

Then, in the function the task is being processed, add a record to the tasks table with percentage 0, return the task id to the front-end so that it can ping for status. Update task percentage after each video

```
# pseudo code

@app.route('/some-url')
def function():
  uuid = random_string
  task = Task(uuid, percentage_completed=0)
  db.session.add(task)
  subprocess run download_vids
  return jsonify({'task_id': uuid})

def download_vids(uuid):
  for i, vid in enumerate(vids):
    # do stuff
    task = db.query(Task).filter_by(uuid=uuid).first()
    task.percentage_completed = (i+1//len(vids) // 100
    db.session.commit()
  # db.session.delete(task) 
  # db.session.commit()

@app.route('/progress/<task_id>') # front-end will ping this each time
def return_stats(task_id):
  task = db.query(Task).filter_by(uuid=uuid).first()
  return jsonify({'progress': task.percentage_completed})
```

This answer uses [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for database transactions.

You might want to have a look at [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) for better handling of tasks.